# Add tag and group names into standard report

Tags: civireport, custom-reports

I need to extend existing Summary and Details contact report with two columns. Filtering is already there, so I only want to see Tag(s) and Groups(s) to which particular contact is assigned.

I've tried to follow some old instruction to create new report, but I have Core Controller error.

Is there any simple way (I'am still novice in coding), to add those two columns into standard reports?